# Can Python substitue JAVA and Objective-C

Tags: android, python, ios, compilation

How can I program in Android using Python 3.x? And what about iOS?

Does it run correctly without further errors to users? Do they need to install something more besides the app written in Python?
This is because I hate JAVA, and I wouldn't like to learn Objective-C so far, so I was looking for an alternative to program Android and iOS Apps.

So, is it possible to program apps for both mobile operating systems with Python? Thank you very much for you attention.

Answer (score 2):

there is [Kivy](http://kivy.org) a crossplateform framework in python

example :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

will display [image: hello world]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run python on Android, you should check out [SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) (Scripting layer for Android). I can't vouch for it's stability/maturity but you can give it a shot.

If you're willing to try Ruby, then [Ruboto](http://ruboto.org/) is a much more stable option.

Comment: The last SL4A release is one year-old. The project doesn't have enough contributors, I'd say.